# how to show fraction with denomainator, horizantal line and numerator on run time in android

Tags: android, equation, algebra, fractions

Is there **any why to show the fraction** neat and clean in android 
denominator, horizontal line and numerator

For example

4/5+x  +  3

would be

4
_____      +      3

5 + x

Actually i want to show the algebraic equation on run time.

please tell me the answer i am working on this since four or five days but no success is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**MainActivity Code:**

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
EditText etInput;
LinearLayout resultLayout;
Button btnResult;
ViewTreeObserver mVto;
int widthOfLine;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput);
    btnResult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowRes);
    btnResult.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String temp = etInput.getText().toString().trim();

            if(temp.contains("/")){
                System.out.println("inside if");
                String[] numArr = temp.split("/");
                Log.d("dj", "num1: & num2: "+numArr[0]+" "+numArr[1]);
                showResults(numArr[0], numArr[1]);
            }
            else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Pattern invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    resultLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.showResultLay);

}





protected void showResults(String numerator, String denominator) {

    final LinearLayout linChild = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext()); 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linChild.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    linChild.setLayoutParams(childParams);
    linChild.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


    TextView tvNumerator = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvNumerator.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
    linChild.addView(tvNumerator);

    tvNumerator.setText(numerator);
    tvNumerator.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tvNumerator.setTextSize(25);

    final View dividerView = new View(getBaseContext());
    dividerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    linChild.addView(dividerView);


    final TextView tvDenominator = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tv1Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvDenominator.setLayoutParams(tv1Params);
    linChild.addView(tvDenominator);
    tvDenominator.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tvDenominator.setText(denominator);
    tvDenominator.setTextSize(25);

    mVto = linChild.getViewTreeObserver();
    mVto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            widthOfLine = tvDenominator.getWidth();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5);
            viewParams.width = widthOfLine;
            dividerView.setLayoutParams(viewParams);

        }
    });

    resultLayout.addView(linChild);

}
```

}

**layout file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="dj.numeratordenominator.main.MainActivity" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/showResultLay"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnShowRes"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShowRes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etInput"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it is not working as i was expected. when i writes 1/2  + 3 then it write
      
      1
     _____ 

     2 + 3

Comment: it is not working as i was expected. when i writes 1/2  + 3 then it write
      
      1
     _____ 

     2 + 3

and it is also giving me error at the line similar to this

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

and I replece it with 

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: also i do not want to view on the next layout. i want to view in only one layout and i shall change the text then this layout will also change clicking on button.

Comment: it is also not shown the 2nd divider (/)  if i write 1/2 + 3/4  then 4 is not shown

Comment: i want to do like this.
http://moreheadmathteacher.weebly.com/uploads/2/4/4/7/24471901/2253634_orig.jpg

Comment: I will post the screen shots of this test program

Comment: for 1/2 u need to give 1/2 only, plus +3 is a different issue.. If ur providing the input like 1/2+3 It will consider like 1/(2+3).. U need to do it properly. It provides u the fraction type of view for whatever input u provide.. Think over it...